# Dual Input Signal Conditioners and 4-wire RTDs

Tags: wiring, rtd, signal-conditioning

I am new to electronics/sensors and am working on integrating two RTDs into a DAQ for a school project. I want to use an Omega TXDIN70 signal condition to interface between the DAQ and RTDs, as it has two channels. Looking at the pinout diagram, I can't figure out how to wire a 4-wire RTD into this module. Can someone help me understand how they would connect? The pin-out diagram is below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an industrial interface module, so it uses 3-wire RTDs. If you're okay with some loss of accuracy due to leadwire compensation, just ignore one of the wires (leave it open, do not parallel it) and wire it as shown on the label.

That assumes that the leadwires are all the same length and guage (color doesn't matter).